# Can I download the latest Android NDK and target Android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am new to Android NDK. Can I download the latest NDK and target Android 2.2
OS? I want this to be the minimum version level. Do I need to download an older NDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are aiming, minumum API level for NDK STILL "3". But be aware that some features do require a minimum of API higher (according to official NDK DOCS, the native activities requires API Level 9), a good friend for you is: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Comment: thanks for your replay but i still didn't understand yes or no

Comment: yes you can use the last NDK, and they made big improvements since old ones, now they also support STL and exceptions (i used the CrystaxNDK to solve this big problem, but now stock NDK works great!)

Comment: dose it mean , target phones with android 2.2 will need updates? for example for using STL?

Comment: negative sir, you just need to use an updated NDK. Download last NDK and target 2.2 , don't worry

Comment: last question , where can i see some kind of list what there is in this new ndk that i can use in Android 2.2 ? im reading the DNK docs and its a mess ...